# How to open a SQLite database as readonly in EF Core?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core

Platform: Windows

The SQLite database is in `Program Files` directory, so it is protected and readonly. Writing to the database would require administrator privilege.

So I have to open the database as readonly (readonly mode is acceptable to me since I don't need to write to it).

I tried to add `Mode=ReadOnly` to the connection string, but it does not work. The app would throw an exception saying

> unable to open database file

```cs
string connectionStr= $"Data Source=my.db;Mode=ReadOnly"; 
Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> configurePrescriptionDbContext = o => o.UseSqlite(connectionStr);
```

Comment: Which SQLite driver and version are you using? EF isn't a database driver, it maps query results to objects and can't change how the database driver or the database itself works. `Mode=ReadOnly` works for the `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`. That doesn't mean the driver won't try to create some temporary file though. You *really* shouldn't  be storing data files in `Program Files`. That's what the special `ProgramData` folder is for